# class name in Rails helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I added a 'map' class to a Rails image_tag helper like this

```
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers={{ latitude }}%2C{{ longitude }}", :class => "map" %>
```

I tried to set styles specific to that image with the map class, so that the image wouldn't be visible by default:

```
img {
border: solid 0px black;
}

img .map { visibility: hidden

}
```

However, the map class image is visible by default

The 'map' class is visible in the html.

```
<img alt="Staticmap?size=300x200&amp;sensor=false&amp;zoom=16&amp;markers=40.6891947%2c-74.0444169" class="map" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x200&amp;sensor=false&amp;zoom=16&amp;markers=40.6891947%2C-74.0444169">
```

When I inspect the element, Chrome console shows that its only the styles from `img` that are registering, not `img .map`

Can you see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS should say

```
img.map {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

With the space it is the CSS [element element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) selector. It selects elements inside elements. You are looking to use the [class selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the gap between **IMG** & **.map** class . Write like this:

```
img.map { visibility: hidden}
```

because with space the terminology is changed `img .map` it's said class **.map** within the **img** tag &  `img.map` it's said class **.map** with **img** tag.

Read this for more [What does a space mean in a CSS selector? i.e. What is the difference between .classA.classB and .classA .classB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/difference-between-classa-classb-and-classa-classb-in-css)