# difference between ul:last-child and ul :last-child

Tags: html, css, sass

I am creating a tree with angular inspire by
https://codepen.io/philippkuehn/pen/QbrOaN with a recursive tamplate

I would like the last elements of my tree print as a columns.

The last `<a>` element is accessible with `li a:last-child`. But i didn't find the way to access to only the last `li`

For explain my question title, i tried to access with

`ul li:last-child`

By some kind of mistake i put a space and i saw i didn't get the same result. (i set a background-color for helping)

`ul li :last-child`

What is the difference ? and as optional question, what could be the best way to access the last `li` ?

ps: i am using **sass**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul li:last-child` selects the last `li` element inside the `ul`.

`ul li :last-child` selects the last element (it doesn't matter if it's a `div`, or `p` or any other) inside the `li`.

You can just use the first one.

Comment: I know understand the difference, but it's not working for selecting only the last li ...

Comment: It works, but in a nested ul you will need something like `ul ul li:last-child` etc. to avoid it also selecting the middle ones. Here is a quick demo for it - https://jsfiddle.net/wzxydv51/ hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`ul li:last-child`: The last `li` inside `ul`

`ul li :last-child`: The last of any type inside `li`. This the same as `ul li *:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge `ul li:last-child` will work for last child. not `ul li :last-child`, this represents, **ul inside li**, inside `:last-child`, but which element? Hence `ul li:last-child` should work properly.