# jquery input[type=checkbox]:checked').length always is 0

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have several input check boxes that share a class called checkboxJobSeekerProfile.  I am trying to write an alert that prints how many of them are checked.  For some the alert always show 0 even when several of the check boxes are checked.  Here is my alert

```
alert($('.checkboxJobSeekerProfile input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
```

Here is my html

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxJobSeekerProfile entry_level"
                                                  id="entry_level" value="entry_level">Entry-level</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxJobSeekerProfile mid_level"
                                                  id="mid_level" value="mid_level">Mid-level</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxJobSeekerProfile senior_level"
                                                  id="senior_level" value="senior_level">Senior-level</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxJobSeekerProfile executive"
                                                  id="executive" value="executive">Executive</label>
```

Comment: use **prop('checked')**

Comment: `$('.checkboxJobSeekerProfile:checked').length` .. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, thanks

Comment: @Aaron You're welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can select strictly by:

```
alert($('input[type=checkbox].checkboxJobSeekerProfile:checked').length);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4w45c4t1/)