# Difference between three CSS Selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these CSS selectors? I can't understand what makes that spaces between paragraph and '.'?

- `p .a`
- `p.a`
- `p .a i`

Comment: can you format it right? what is -p?

Comment: looks so !! Now, he formatted right

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for combinators.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c

Comment: I have added an format fix. please remove the `{}` (stack overflow requires at least 6 fixes)

Comment: This was asked literally not even half a day ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `p`:

- `p .a` - all elements with the class `a` inside paragraphs. (The fancy term for the space there is [*descendant combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).)
- `p.a` - all paragraphs that have the class `a`.
- `p .a i` - all  `i`(italic) elements inside elements with `a` class that are inside paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for making it better

Comment: Don't answer to duplicate questions please