# Need an explanation on responsive top menu (hamburger) from w3school example

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am studying on how to create a responsive (hamburger) menu bar using vanilla JavaScript. This is a code from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) and I usually understand the concept because they provide an explanation. However, this example throws me off and I have 3 parts where I do not get it. I appreciate a clarification.

1. In CSS, why is there no space between `.topnav` and `.responsive`? Isn't responsive supposed to follow after .`topnav`? The result shows differently when I put space between two classes. Same goes to `a.icon`. Why isn't there space between a and `.icon`?
2. I read this meaning `javascript:void(0);` on Stack Overflow but I still do not get it as the meaning seems universal.
3. `x.className += " responsive";` Is it creating a new class called `responsive`?

Thank you very much in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. [What does a space mean in a CSS selector? I.e. What is the difference between `.classA.classB` and `.classA .classB`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1126338/4642212) 2. `<a href="javascript: void 0;">` is bad practice — the link should really be a button. It creates a link that has no linking action like adding a fragment identifier like `#home`. 3. It _adds_ a class name so that the relevant CSS rules apply. Would be written as `x.classList.add("responsive")` in modern sites. You should avoid asking multiple questions per post.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for examples and link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, just answering your questions here:

1. Having no space between `.topnav` and `.responsive` means it will select an element with both class names. If you add the space in between, you would be selected all (if any) element having the `responsive` class name with a parent (or grandparent, or grand-grand-...-parent) having a `topnav` class name.
2. Basically, `javascript:void(0);` means "do nothing". The `javascript:` part means the following part is coded in javascript and the `void(0)` is a statement that does nothing and returns undefined, in javascript.
3. The line `x.className += " responsive";` adds the `responsive` class name to the x element. If `x` had the class name `topnav`, after this line it will have both class names, matching the `.topnav.responsive` CSS selector.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you. It has solved my curiosity.