# Class selector "p .class" not working CSS

Tags: html, css, class, flexbox

I start to run out of ideas. I'm using flexbox inside flexboxes, and somehow even tho somewhere else on my page I use it, here I'm not able to reach "h1 .class" or "p .class".

My HTML:

```
                <div class="corediv">
                    <div class="coreimg">   
                        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="coretext">  
                        <h1>TEXTTEXTEXT</h1>
                        <p>TEXTTEXTEXT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to select those particularly because I want to have no space between header and paragraph. Thus I tried to put margins to 0.

With following CSS:

```
h1 .coretext {
   margin-botton: 0px;
}

p .coretext {
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

And so to ensure it wasn't managing to affect h1 and p, I also added some "color: red" and "font-size: x-large;".

But nothing seems to be able to reach thoses h1 and p.

Obviously, when I directly calls h1 or p with:

```
h1 {
   color: red;
}
```

It works.

Any insight on this? I've been trying quite everything I found online and since english isn't my native langage, I might have been taping the wrong keyword somehow, because I hardly believe I'm the first one to encounter this.

Thank you in advance for your time :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with your current code. First of all this selector `h1 .coretext` will target any *children* of a `<h1>` element with the class of `coretext`.

There was also a typo contained in your code `margin-botton` - I'm not going to insult your intelligence, I'm assuming this was just a mistyped character, but it will have been causing you issues.

To target elements that are inside the element with the class`coretext` you can use the following selectors:

```css
.coretext h1 {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.coretext p {
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="corediv">
  
  <div class="coreimg">   
    <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coretext">  
    <h1>TEXTTEXTEXT</h1>
    <p>TEXTTEXTEXT</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of spoonfeeding code to OP, please consider explaining how your code differs from OP's code (as well as links to the documentation if necessary).

Comment: @Edric I posted the code to help the OP and was in the process of editing to expand upon my answer.

Comment: Hey @DannyXCII, thanks a lot for the quick answer!

As you said, the typo in "botton" instead of bottom, comes from the fact I retyped my CSS code here to avoid copy/pasting useless informations.

What I don't really get is why in another part of my css "header .nav-list" work, but here "p .coretext" doesn't work but ".coretext p" does?

Is it because as you are saying the h1 and p are inside a div with that class and not directly "tagged" with that class?

I found the logic of writting it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Thanks a lot one again

Comment: @Noskeal `header .nav-list {}` will style **any** children of the `<header>` with the class `nav-list` - check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/WinningWebDesign/pen/PoPymby) which should help demonstrate a little better. `h1 .coretext` will style any elements with the class `coretext` that are nested within a `<h1>` tag.

Comment: @DannyXCII Thanks again, it was really a lack of knowledge on that from me. Saw it too with this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c
Thanks again for your time and patience.