# What is the difference in writing these two codes?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I was just experimenting with it but I came up with a confusion in my code.
Below are the two code fragments:

1.

```
.box h1 {
   font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
}
```

2.

```
h1 .box {
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`.box` is a class that I have written for my code.
Please tell me what difference it is when we write the code 1 & 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a space mean in a CSS selector? i.e. What is the difference between .classA.classB and .classA .classB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c)

Comment: the first means: all `h1` inside `.box` get that style applied. numbe 2 means all `.box` in `h1` get this style applied. usually nobody use number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code 1

```
.box h1 {
   font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
}
```

It is looking for h1 tag inside tag with class .box. and will update the style of that h1
ie.

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

**Some text** here will have style   font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;text-align: center;

In Code 2

```
h1 .box {
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It is looking for class .box inside h1 tag

ie.

```
<h1><span class="box">Some</span>Text</h1>
```

Here styles will be applicable on **Some** only

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

.box h1 are **h1** elements inside **.box** elements

h1 .box are **.box** elements inside **h1** elements

Answer (score 1):

If you put a selector immediately after another, it selects all matching elements of the second selector that are descendants of elements with the first selector.

Example:

```
<h1>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</h1>
```

All the `div`s above would be matched by `h1 .box`. If you flip it around to `.box h1`, the selector would return all `h1`s that are descendants of elements with class `box`, which is none in this case.

Comment: thank you! now its much clearer

Comment: @AnishVijay no problem