# style issue in nested tags

Tags: html, css, nested

I need to change some style for a list in css. Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="is-sticky">
   <div class="menu">
      <ul class="sub-menu"> ...... </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add  css like

```
.is-sticky.sub-menu {
     top:10px;
}
```

But this is not working

Comment: you missed space between: `.is-sticky .sub-menu`

Comment: like @demkovych noted you forgot the space. when you dont add the space it will only apply to elements that have both the is-sticky class and the sub-menu class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.is-sticky .sub-menu {
     top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

currently what you are doing to access the child element's (sub-menu) class is that you
use

```
.is-sticky.sub-menu {
     top:10px;
}
```

without a space , but when you add a space between is-sticky and sub-menu like so:

```
.is-sticky .sub-menu {
     top:10px;
}
```

you access the sub-menu class inside is-sticky class.

[What does a space mean in a CSS selector? i.e. What is the difference between .classA.classB and .classA .classB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c)

> .classA.classB refers to an element that has both classes A and B
> (class="classA classB"); whereas .classA .classB refers to an element
> with class="classB" descended from an element with class="classA".