# select multiple classes including nested scss class

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add the same styling to multiple classes, including a nested SASS class like so

```
  .class1,
  .class2,
  .class3,
  .class4.class4child,
  .class5 {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 3.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
  }
```

I'm hoping `class4.class4child` will inherit these properties, but this implementation doesn't seem to work. (class1,2,3,5 all work here)

edit: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c), as I was not aware of both syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 .class4.class4child,
```

which only applies to elements that have **both** classes, with

```
 .class4 .class4child,
```

which applies to elements with `class="class4child"` which are *descendants* to an element with `class="class4"`.

Comment: Wow, that simple. Thank you